# How to programmatically check if appbar is present in flutter app, or not?

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, flutter-appbar

Is there any way to store in a boolean variable true for if appbar is present and false if not? I can't find at all anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default AppBar in flutter like Android have ActionBar depends on theme.

You are owner of top most widget and you should know whether you provided appbar widget or not.

So there is no way to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold.of(context).hasAppBar
```